# Optimising a foreach loop write to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table of data where I update multiple rows in one transaction. The Foreach loop below works perfectly, however if the table contains a large number of rows there is a fair delay, presumably while the whole table is worked through line by line.

Even if I only change one field in one line, there is a significant delay (20 seconds), which again I am assuming is because the loop is working through each line.

```
//get data from form
$id2 = $_POST['id2'];
$status2 = $_POST['status2'];
$comment = $_POST['comments2'];

foreach ($id2 as $key2 => $value2){
$query3 = "UPDATE newthing SET comments='$comment[$key2]' WHERE id = $value2 ";
$query4 = "UPDATE newthing SET status='$status2[$key2]' WHERE id = $value2 ";

//execute query
mysql_query($query3);
mysql_query($query4);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of undertaking this task? I am open to learning as required if there is a java / ajax / any other sort of tool to use. Additionally, I am aware that mysql_query is old now, so if there's a PDO method of doing this, so much the better. I haven't got my head around PDO at all yet :-/

Many thanks,
Jason

Comment: Are both queries updating the same row of the same table (like your example suggests)?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would like to have a word with you!

Comment: @RossWilson - yes, that's correct. There are potentially two fields in each line that are updated in this query, however I have other versions of the same query where there may be five or six fields in each line that could (but aren't always) updated.

Comment: Mark Bakers answer is the one you're looking for.

Comment: @AmalMurali :) I know, however this is on a completely internal network, no outside link and only internal people using it, all of whom have access to the database so could inject what they like. I take your point though, and do really need to update it :)

Comment: Write some javascript that detects which fields the user changed, and only submits those ones.  Right now you are updating everything on the page, even stuff that was left alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by merging into a single update:

```
foreach ($id2 as $key2 => $value2){
    $query3 = "UPDATE newthing SET comments='$comment[$key2]', status='$status2[$key2]' WHERE id = $value2 ";

    //execute query
    mysql_query($query3);
}
```

Then start learning about prepared statements/bind variables with the MySQLi or PDO extensions to replace the deprecated MySQL extension, and to help prevent SQL injection

Comment: Fabulous, thanks for this. I didn't realise I could merge into a single update. I'll do this right now.

Comment: this is great and has made a difference on the test database. I'm just about to make see about the live...    Many thanks for your swift help.